# Is it possible to achieve the so-called "distraction free mode" in Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

Just curious, kinda like the "distraction free mode" of editors like [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/distraction-free-editing), is it possible to centroid all the text to the middle of view field? It's always annoying to stare at the left-most end of the vim terminal in fullscreen mode with a widescreen monitor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could take a look at VimRoom:
http://projects.mikewest.org/vimroom/

Alternatively, you could set Vim up to have two or more vertical windows on your widescreen and have the same buffer automatically "snake" between them.  Allows you to see two or three times as much of your buffer on the screen at once.  See here for that option:
[auto-scrollable pagination with vim using vertical split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873076/auto-scrollable-pagination-with-vim-using-vertical-split)

Answer (score 0):

try autohotkey which use to control windows hotkey press and gui

this is my autohotkey script which use to lauch Gvim

```
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ;set ahk title mode
    run C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe ;lauch gvim
    winactivate, No Name ; active this window
    sleep, 500 ; sleep 500ms
    WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, [Vim default title] ;hide title bar
    WinSet, Transparent, 200, [Vim default title] ;make vim backgroup Transparent
```