# How to disable backspace and delete keys in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'd like to use Vim for distraction-free writing instead of PyRoom/TextRoom. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8484190/1768191), which mentions VimRoom, could already show me how to get most settings.

I only miss how to enable TextRoom style flow mode:

How can I disable backspace and delete keys (not shortcuts like d$)?

Comment: How does a disabled backspace promote "distraction free" writing? Just make typos and leave them because it's distracting to correct yourself? Some background rationale would improve this question.

Comment: @Kaz It's about the flow. When you write prose, it's a good idea to keep writing and to not think about every single word or mistake that you make. The goal is to get flowing and bring the stream of ideas from your head to text, without stopping yourself along the way. I never tried it for writing code, but the same "get into flow"-idea might be true as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can disable individual keys by mapping them to the special `<Nop>` target:

```
:inoremap <BS> <Nop>
:inoremap <Del> <Nop>
```

(Assuming you only want them disabled in insert mode.)

Comment: Totally answered my question!

Answer (score -1):

You can flow without vim, by making a shell scripts that reads from the tty in raw mode and does not allow most control characters, including backspace and DEL, and echoes things twice: once directly to the terminal, and once to standard output so you can redirect your work to a file.

```
#!/bin/sh

saved_tty=$(stty -g < /dev/tty)

bail()
{
  stty $saved_tty < /dev/tty
  exit $?
}

trap bail EXIT INT

stty raw -echo < /dev/tty

while true ; do
  ch=$(dd bs=1 count=1 < /dev/tty 2> /dev/null)
  code=$(printf "%d" "'$ch")
  if [ $code -eq 4 ] ; then
    printf "\r\n" > /dev/tty
    printf "\n"
    break
  elif [ $code -eq 13 -o $code -eq 10 ] ; then
    printf "\r\n" > /dev/tty
    printf "\n"
  elif [ $code -ge 32 -a $code -lt 127 ] ; then
    printf "%s" "$ch" > /dev/tty
    printf "%s" "$ch"
  fi
done
```

Save this as `flow`, `chmod a+x flow` and just:

```
$ flow > file.txt
Backspace and del not allowed
here just type and type.
Then hit Ctrl-D when you're done; no Enter
required.

$ flow
ffoorrggoott  ttoo  rreeddiirreecctt!!
```

If you require a blank screen, `clear` first or add screen clearing to the script.

Comment: While clever, this isn't really answering the question asked.

Comment: @jskulski X-Y problem. Question asks for X but the real problem is Y. This answer addresses Y: implementation of a program which allows "flow" entry of text (which can be easily massaged with Vim afterward).  Not clever at all, just basic shell scripting.